# Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+25y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+25y=0$

Given the boundary conditions: $y(0)=1,\frac{dy}{dx}(0)=0$

So far, I've worked out the complementary function:

$e^{-3x}(A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x))$

But I don't know what I need to do regarding the particular integral.

According to the solution $y(0)=1 \implies A=1$.

But I don't understand why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y(x) = e^{-3x}(A\cos(4x) + B\sin(4x))$, what is $y(0)$?

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot now! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry about feeling like an idiot, by the time you solve 30 equations like this one, substituting the initial conditions will be as obvius to you as the fact that the sun rises in the east.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the solution of the ode, which is $y(x) = e^{-{3x}}(A\cos{4x} + B\sin{4x})$, substitute back the **initial** conditions, v.g. $y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 0$ and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Cheers.